# Correlation Corrgram Configuration

Tags: r, correlation

I built a correlation matrix with the corrgram package and I done some configuration. I would like to use the spearman correlation method. Is it possible with this code?

```
panel.shadeNtext <- function (x, y, corr = NULL, col.regions, ...) 
{
   corr <- cor(x, y, use = "pair")
   results <- cor.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided")
   est <- results$p.value
   stars <- ifelse(est < 0.001, "***", 
              ifelse(est < 0.01, "**", 
                     ifelse(est < 0.05, "*", "")))
   ncol <- 14
   pal <- col.regions(ncol)
   col.ind <- as.numeric(cut(corr, breaks = seq(from = -1, to = 1, 
                                                length = ncol + 1), include.lowest = TRUE))
usr <- par("usr")
rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col = pal[col.ind], 
   border = NA)
box(col = "lightgray")
on.exit(par(usr))
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
r <- formatC(corr, digits = 2, format = "f")
cex.cor <- .4/strwidth("-X.xx")
fonts <- ifelse(stars != "", 2,1)
text(0.5, 0.5, paste0(r,"\n", stars), cex = cex.cor)
}

# Generate some sample data
sample.data <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

# Call the corrgram function with the new panel functions
corrgram(sample.data, type="data", lower.panel=panel.shadeNtext, 
        upper.panel=NULL,cor.method="spearman")
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but why not just change in the `panel.shadeNtext` function the `corr <- cor(x, y, use="pair")` line to `corr <- cor(x, y, use="pair", method="spearman")`?